# Showing existence of a solution to an underdetermined system of equations with non-negativity constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, markov-chains, queueing-theory

Let $K$ be a positive integer, let $p\in (0,1)$, and let $\{W(k,i),W^B(k,i), \varphi_k(i)\}_{1\leq i\leq k\leq K}$ be variables.

I need to prove that there exists a solution to the following system of equations:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
W(k,i) & =\; & (1-p)\cdot W^B(k,i) &\\
&+ & p\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\varphi_{k}(j)\cdot\left(W\left(k-1,i-1\right)+1\right) & \forall 1 \leq i\leq k\leq K\\
&+ & p\cdot\sum_{j=i+1}^{k}\varphi_{k}(j)\cdot\left(W\left(k-1,i\right)+1\right)& \\ 
W^{B}\left(k,i\right) & = &\; (1-p) \cdot\left(W\left(k,i\right)+1\right) + p\cdot W^{B}\left(k+1,i\right) & \;\; \forall 1 \leq k<K\\
W^{B}\left(k,i\right) & = &\; W\left(k,i\right)+1  & \text{ if } k=K \\
\sum_{i=1}^k \varphi_k(i) &=& 1 & \forall 1 \leq k \leq K \\
W^{B}\left(k,k\right) &=& W^{B}\left(1,1\right) & \forall 1 \leq k\leq K\\
\varphi_k(i) &\geq & 0  & \forall 1 \leq i \leq k \leq K 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I could manually calculated solutions for $K\in {2,3,4}$, for example there is a unique solution for $K=2$ in which $\varphi_2(1) = \frac{1}{3-p} $. As $K$ becomes larger the problem becomes underdetermined, and I could manually solve to find a family of solution for $K=3$, but I do not know how to show that a solution exists for any $K$.

I also know (from Little's law) that for valid solutions $W^B(k,k) = \frac{K+1}{2p}$.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!

**Background:**

The first three sets of equations equations characterize the expected waiting time of an agent who joins a queue with maximal size $K$. The variables $\{\varphi_k(i)\} _{1\leq i \leq k}$ determine the queue policy. The question is equivalent to showing that there exists a queueing policy that randomizes assignments so that the expected wait for agents who join the queue is the same regardless of the position they join.

Here is the description of the stochastic system. Time is discrete and every period starts with an arrival of an item. With probability $p$ the item is of kind $A$, in which case the item is assigned to an agent on the queue, and the period ends. With probability $1-p$ the item is of kind $B$, in which case agents may join the queue while the system will try to assign the $B$ item. The system draws agents who might take the $B$ item. With probability $1-p$ a drawn agent (of type $\beta$) takes the $B$ item and the period ends; With probability $p$ a drawn agent (of type $\alpha$) joins the queue and the system continues to draw agents. If there are $K$ agents on the queue the next agent takes the $B$ (regardless of whether it is $\alpha$ or $\beta$), and the period ends.

The policy can select which agent on the queue should receive the arriving $A$ item. For a queue of maximal size $K$, we set the probabilities $\left\{ \varphi\left(i,k\right)\right\} _{1\leq i\leq k\leq K}$ where $\varphi_{k}\left(i\right)$ is the probability that the agent in position $i$ will receive an arriving $A$ item when there are $k$ agents on the queue. Agents move to the next position if someone ahead of them is assigned. Some agent must always be assigned, so $\sum_{i\leq k}\varphi_{k}\left(i\right)=1$.
[image: States and transitions of the system (only states >0 are relevant)]

Denote the expected wait until assignment of an agent in position $i$ out of $k$ agents at the beginning of the period by $W(i,k)$. Denote expected wait until assignment of an agent in position $i$ out of $k$ agents when the system is looking to allocate a $B$ item by $W^{B}(i,k)$.

The first three sets of equations correspond to the possible transitions, and determine the expected waiting times. The remaining equations ask that assignment probabilities sum to $1$ and are non-negative, and that all agents have the same expected wait when they join the queue.

Here is a [link to the paper](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/jacob.leshno/Research/Leshno%20-%20Dynamic%20Matching%20in%20Waiting%20Lists.pdf) from which the question arises. Appendix C contains additional examples.